# Plot a one variable function with different values for parameters?

Tags: plotting

I need to plot `f(m)` vs `m` the function

```
f(m) = t m^2 + c m^3 + u m^4
```

For different values of `t, c`, and `u.` For

```
f[x_] := x^4 + a*x^2
```

this can be done by using

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Labeled[f[x], a], {a, {1, 20, 100}}]], {x, 0, 3}]
```

How to generalize it for `f(m)`? Please help.

Comment: Huh?  Why not merely plot $f(m)$ directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For different values of t, c, and u. For

If I understand you right, why not use Manipulate? This is exactly what it is designed for

[image]

**code**

```
Manipulate[ 
 Module[{m},
  Plot[t*m^2 + c*m^3 + u*m^4, {m, -extend, extend}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ,
 {{extend, 3, "domain length"}, .1, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{t, -88, "t"}, -200, 200, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, -54, "c"}, -100, 100, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{u, 3, "u"}, -100, 100, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {extend, t, c, u}
 ]
```